# Access one instance in different controllers views along with its own instance in Grails?

Tags: grails, view

Access one instance in different controllers views along with its own instance in Grails?
My scenario:

> Status controller with _list.gsp template that lists all the statuses.
>   User Instance has politic profile and education profile.
>   I want to render _list.gsp on to political's list.gsp or education's show.gsp
>   My status's _list.gsp looks like this:

```
<g:each in="${statusInstanceList}" status="i" var="statusInstance">
<td>${fieldValue(bean: statusInstance, field: "statusMessage")}</td>
```

> and I want to render the _list.gsp template on politic profile like this

```
<g:each in="${politicItemList.sort{it.dateCreated}}" status="i" var="politicItemInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
                  <td>${fieldValue(bean: politicItemInstance, field: "politicItemName.name")}
    <g:render template="/status/list"/>
```

> rest is working fine but its not loading up the values
>   I am not sure how to make a class or instance available globally or across all areas on the application.

Comment: Showcasing the domains, controllers at least with dummy values/variables will be easy to understand and helpful to answer? "A problem well stated is a problem half solved" dear friend. :)

Comment: I have updated the main question... hope this will clearify the problem a bit.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you can see, template _list.gsp uses `statusInstanceList` which should be fetched from the model related to the action which renders the template. In this case the action from `Status` controller.

You are trying to render this template in politic profile. In order to render `_list.gsp` template you have to feed the template with `statusInstanceList`. right? How can you do that?

Before rendering the template you have to either do a `remoteFunction` call to the Status controller to get the status list OR add status list to politic profile model and pass it on to the _list template.

Programatically, for example:

```
Status Controller:-

def statusAction(){
   render(template: "list", model: [statusInstanceList: statusInstanceList])
}

Profile controller:=

def profileAction(){
   //Get the statusInstanceList here to set in the model somethinglike
   def actionResponse = g.include(action: 'statusAction', controller: 'status')
   def statusInstanceList = actionResponse.statusInstanceList
   render(template: "profilelist", model: [politicItemList: politicItemList, statusInstanceList: statusInstanceList])
}

You can do something like:

_profileList.gsp

<g:each in="${politicItemList.sort{it.dateCreated}}" status="i" var="politicItemInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
                  <td>${fieldValue(bean: politicItemInstance, field: "politicItemName.name")}
    <g:render template="/status/list" model="[statusInstanceList: statusInstanceList]"/>
```

If you do not want to fetch the response of Status Action in Profile Controller, then you can add `g:include` in the profileList template as

`<g:include controller="status" action="statusAction" />`

This will include the response from the status action to profileList template. See  for details.

Comment: Nice... I will give it a go and get back to you.. Thanks

Comment: It says: No such property: statusInstanceList for class: iwiora.users.PoliticController

Comment: Do I import class on politic controller and status controller too? I am sorry I am fairly new to grails

Comment: Now I am getting this error when trying to render statusList on politicList view
No such property: statusInstanceList for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.StreamCharBuffer

Comment: solved the probelm:
politicItemList: PoliticItem.findAllByUserAccount(userAccount), statusInstanceList: Status.findAllByUserAccount(userAccount)
Instead of using: statusInstanceList: statusInstanceList])
}
which basically finds all the instances by session user